# Quotient Cohen-Macaulay ring and associated primes

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay-rings

Does there exist such (local) Cohen-Macaulay Noetherian ring $(R,m)$ with some $p\in \operatorname{Ass}R$ so that $R/p$ is not Cohen-Macaulay? (I am especially curious about the case where $R$ is a Cohen-Macaulay affine ring (i.e. $R=k[x_1,...,x_n]/I$ for some ideal $I\in k[x_1,...,x_n]$ where $k$ is a field) if we don't assume $R$ to be local.)
[related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4415071) from MSE.

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  Begin with an irreducible surface $S$ in affine $n$-space, $n\geq 4$, with an isolated non-unibranch point.  Then let $R$ be the localization at this of the coordinate ring of a sufficiently general complete intersection of $n-2$ high degree hypersurfaces containing $S$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Dear Jason, Thank you for your comment. I am not so familiar with geometric view towards these, but I think I get the point. However, I wonder if it is possible to give such an example concretely and algebraically ?  Maybe it just needs one to construct the surfaces with the properties you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Inside affine $4$-space with variables $x,y,z,w$, consider the complete intersection of codimension $2$ with defining equations $xw-yz=xz^2-y^2w=0$.  This contains as one irreducible component the non-Cohen-Macaulay zero locus $xw-yz=xz^2-y^2w=z^3-yw^2=y^3-zx^2=0$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks, that makes more sense to me.